# shell commands in mongo inside Docker fails for Authentication

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run some shell commands in mongo which is inside docker container.

```
docker exec -it mongodb_mock  bash
```

It opens the mongo shell. but when I run any command in this it gives authentication error:

```
    > show dbs
2018-08-28T10:12:12.755+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:62:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:781:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:671:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

Please help.

EDIT: This db is created through mongoose/express, from another container.

Comment: you ran mongod deamon with --auth option so you should authorize with admin user then only you can perform any query

Answer (score 2):

first you need to authorize db with user, below is example command

```
use admin;
db.auth('admin','password');
```

then your able to run all querys. or start mongod without --auth parameter so you no need user authentication.

Comment: > db.auth("admin", "admin")
Error: Authentication failed.

Comment: please check username and password are correct? and replace double quotes with single quote, i have added another command